# Invitation from Careers OpenID Issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, openid, user-accounts

I am having an issue accepting my Careers invitation. I get the following error:

> Hmm, that email already exists on another account. You will need to log out of your   existing account and log back in.

I was using a Google OpenID on Stack Overflow that was different from the one I used to authorize Careers but had the same details.

(Google apps accounts migration issue; I won't go into details.)

I tried to rectify the issue by associating my Stack Overflow account with my new Google OpenID, and removing the defunct one; both my StackOverflow and Careers have matching OpenIDs.

However it didn't help and I am still getting that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that, you should be all set now. Try again?

Comment: Thanks, it's working perfectly now.